# Is there a difference between Set and set?

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

I am using Python 2.7, and just wondering if there is any difference between `set()` and `Set()` (i.e. with/without the capitalization).

Specifically, the Python instructions https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html suggest that Sets should be imported and initialized as:

```
from sets import Set
x = Set()
```

I have just been using the command set() without importing anything, i.e.:

```
x = set()
```

Just wondering if these are identical, or if they are somehow different.

Comment: At the foot of the docs page you've linked to, there's a [comparison of the two](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#comparison-to-the-built-in-set-types) which lists the differences.

Comment: That module was deprecated in 2.6. Just use `set`.

Comment: "Deprecated since version 2.6: The built-in set/frozenset types replace this module." So, Set is the deprecated version of set.

Comment: did you read the docs you linked to?

Comment: @Asad - thanks - not really sure how i missed the big red box at the top of the instruction page saying that...

Answer (score 1):

As it says in Python documentation the [`Set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#sets.Set) class provides every `set` method except for [`__hash__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__).

> For advanced applications requiring a hash method, the ImmutableSet class adds a **hash**() method but omits methods which alter the contents of the set. Both Set and ImmutableSet derive from BaseSet, an abstract class useful for determining whether something is a set: isinstance(obj, BaseSet).

Answer (score 1):

I have no any deep knowledge on them - honestly until I saw your question, I thought that they were identical.

Now checked

```
>>> from sets import Set
>>> x = Set()
>>> y = set()
>>> len(dir(y))
54
>>> len(dir(x))
63
```

and realized that they have some dfferences

```
>>> Y = set(dir(y))
>>> X = set(dir(x))
>>> X-Y
set(['_compute_hash', '__module__', '_update', '_binary_sanity_check', '__setstate__', '__deepcopy__', '_repr', '__as_immutable__', 'union_update', '__slots__', '__copy__', '__as_temporarily_immutable__', '_data', '__getstate__'])    
>>> Y-X
set(['__rand__', '__ror__', '__rsub__', '__rxor__', 'isdisjoint'])
```

Ofcourse this doesn't give any clear information on their differences, but shows that they are not identical :)